# Is $ℝ^2$ a subspace of $ℝ^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my opinion, since no linear combination from $ℝ^3$ can form any vector in $ℝ^2$ so the answer is no?

Comment: The subspace $\{ (x,y,0) \, | \, x,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Formally, no. But is not too far-fetched to view $\mathbb{R^2}$ as $\mathbb{R^2} \times \{ 0 \}$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

This is similar in spirit to us saying that $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ even though it is formally not. (But $x \in \mathbb{R}$ can be naturally identified with $x+i0 \in \mathbb{C}$.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can write $\mathbb{R}^2$ as  $\mathbb{R}^2\times \lbrace 0 \rbrace\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is, strictly speaking, not the same as $\mathbb{R}^2\times \{0\}$, and $(x,y)$ is not the same as $(x,y,0)$, but as has been noted by others, the spaces are isomorphic.

Comment: In linear algebra are identic.

Comment: No. Regardless of the context, $(x,y,0)$ is different from $(x,y)$.